# Is there any java api method to round negative value to zero

Tags: java

I want to round negative value to zero.
Eg: -223.5 to 0.0. Is there any specific methods in Java?

Comment: what is the need of an API when you are just doing a if statement to check whether it is negative or not!!

Comment: amazing, people learn to use APIs before they learn assigning values to variables and `if` statement...

Comment: Using APIs creates readable, meaningful code. This is Java, not C

Comment: Could you please go into further detail as to why you have found yourself in this situation? What drove you to this logic? Elaborate please.

Answer (score 6):

```
int nonNegative =  Math.max(yourValue, 0);
double nonNegativeDouble =  Math.max(yourValueAsDouble, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Ternary operator:

```
a = a<0 ? 0 : a;
```

If statement:

```
if (a<0) a = 0;
```

Don't use methods or APIs just for the sake of it. ["KISS" principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) would I think apply well in that case.

My personal opinion about APIs is that you should use them if it makes your code more readable, more maintainable, don't reinvent the wheel and/or you don't repeat yourself.

In that case, I think that what you want to do can be achieved as a simple conditionnal single-line statement and as such, you don't benefit from using an API.

But indeed, that can also be achieved as stated in another answer using the `Math.max` function:

```
a = Math.max(a, 0);
```

Comment: +1 for the "KISS" principle. :)

Comment: I disagree. Effective Java, Item 47: Know and use the libraries

Comment: Well in that particular case, I personally find it clearer to use a conditionnal statement (be it an IF or a ternary operator) than a call to Math.max function. But in lots of other cases I would agree with you.

Comment: As my value is retived from some caluculation and i cany use Ternary operator or If statement. Math.max(a, 0) is much appropriate for me. Thanks All.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the Math.max methods also take care of some edge cases and therefore give consistent behaviour: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 4):

Thats it:

```
float a = -223.5;
if(a < 0)
    a = 0.0;
```